# Filter character vector based on first two elements

Tags: r

I have a vector that look like this:

```
data <- c("0115", "0159", "0256", "0211")
```

I want to filter the data based on the first 2 elements of my vector. For example:

group 1 - elements that start with `01`

group 2 - elements that start with `02`

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use [Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) (regex) to find strings that start with "01" or "02".

Base approach is use `grep()`, which returns indices of strings that match a pattern. Here's an example - notice I've changed the 2nd and 4th data elements to demonstrate how just searching for "01" or "02" will lead to incorrect answer:

```
d <- c("0115", "0102", "0256", "0201")

grep("01", d)
#> [1] 1 2 4

d[grep("01", d)]
#> [1] "0115" "0102" "0201"
```

Because this searches for "01" anywhere, you get "0201" in the mix. To avoid, add "^" to the pattern to specify that the string **starts with** "01":

```
grep("^01", d)
#> [1] 1 2

d[grep("^01", d)]
#> [1] "0115" "0102"
```

If you use the stringr package, you can also use `str_detect()` in the same way:

```
library(stringr)

d[str_detect(d, "^01")]
#> [1] "0115" "0102"
```